# Highlight the reputation number when cap is reached for the day

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, information-display, daily-reputation-limit

It's kind of a pain (when you have a bunch of downvotes you gave or got) to have to compute your rep in the 'Recent Activity' page to see how far you are from the cap.  How about we change the color of the rep shown, when the rep cap has been reached for 'Today'?  I think it'd be best to have this visible no matter what time frame you're in, even though it only applies to the 'Today' rep cap.  Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[alt text http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1599/repcolor.png](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1599/repcolor.png)

**Edit:** As Shog9 pointed out, this would help reduce confusion.  If there was a tooltip on it also explaining what it meant, it might cut down on all the rep-cap questions we get on Meta.

**Edit2:**  I think some people are getting the wrong idea.  It's not about holding off on answering questions, it's about striving to answer more and better so that I can reach the cap.  It's to help motivate more activity, not to lessen it.  One of the purposes of rep is to incentivize asking and answering questions, so by letting someone know they're getting closer to the rep cap, they'll be motivated to answer more.

This also works for the Mortarboard, Legendary and Epic badges since those are directly related to the rep-cap.  I hope someday to get all those particular badges, so a little bit of help from site with bookkeeping will help keep me pushing.  I'm always able to work better with a goal in sight, one of the strengths I believe of the StackOverflow sites.

Comment: Is too much reputation keeping people from answering questions?

Comment: No, it's not about not answering.  It's about working a little harder at it maybe, a little motivation to push a bit.

Comment: The number should be animated with golden sparkles when the rep cap has been reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try my Greasemonkey script (see this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23656/greasemonkey-script-to-gold-plate-sofu) for details). Amongst other things it displays your daily rep on the link bar.

**Update:** *I'd not used this for a while, it looks like the change to the daily reputation page has broken the calculation for the rep. I'll have a look at fixing this shortly.*

**Update 2:** I just uploaded another version of the script. It works on my box<sup>TM</sup>

Comment: @snicker, thanks. One day I'm going to collect on all those infringements

Comment: Could you update this to work with the new format that has changed the top bar?

Answer (score 2):

Or simply, you can answer questions also, for the first purpose, which is providing a solution to someone, besides the "earn reputation" goal.

Such "feature" can only push some people to post less answers, I don't see why there would be an advantage in implementing such a thing.

Comment: People already check their rep-cap (including Jon Skeet).  This isn't about creating a new activity, it's about making a current activity smoother.

Comment: The less time I spend satisfying my curiosity about where I am in relation to the rep-cap, the more time I can spend answering questions.

Comment: @Lance - Making a use case "smoother" is actually pushing people to do it more. And besides, I don't believe that "optimizing your time wondering about rep cap" is increasing the amount of answers you write. The best way to increase that is to not think about rep cap.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps reduce confusion about the cap, then it's probably worthwhile. Not sure a simple color change is enough for that though; a key or footnote might help.

Otherwise, seems kinda pointless; you can almost always tell when you've hit the cap 'cause up-votes don't contribute any rep!

Answer (score 2):

I just use my [Reputation Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx) - when the number reaches 200, you've hit the cap.

(Works across different sites, too.)

Of course, I'm somewhat biased...

Comment: Do you really need a program to tell you if you've hit the rep cap on a given day? I could do that for you, easily. You'll hit it today. And tomorrow. And the next day. And the next...