# You've reached your daily cap icon

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlight the reputation number when cap is reached for the day.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36614/highlight-the-reputation-number-when-cap-is-reached-for-the-day)

> **Update**
>   I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, I just haven't been able to find it. Will delete my question if you show me it is one.

Hi everyone,

I find it quite hard realizing when I've hit the daily rep cap, mostly due to the fact that some upvotes count towards the cap, while others don't.

Take today for example, I've just gone to my Recent Activity and have clicked on the `today` tab to find that I've acquired 243 reputation. Why didn't I hit the cap at 200? When will I hit the cap? I just have no idea.

StackOverflow shouldn't be a points race, but if I've hit nearly 250 rep points in one day, I've probably spent enough time answering questions and I should do some work.

Would anyone like to see a little icon in the header toolbar which indicates the daily cap has been reached? I certainly would.

Comment: Okay, the question IS a duplicate and there is a GreaseMonkey script that does this. I'll delete the question in 10 minutes.

Comment: Actually, it's probably best to close the question instead, I hate deleting other user's information. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and scroll to the very bottom.

You'll see something like this:

```
 ...
 2   3808773 (10)
 2   3809241 (10)  << still receiving points
 2   3809241 [0]   << boom! cap exceeded
 1   3809204 [15]  << cap exceeded, but still get points for accepts
 2   3809058 [0]
 2   3809204 [0]
 2   3809204 [0]
 2   3809159 [0]
 2   3682202 [0]
 1   3808636 [15]
 2   3808636 [0]
 2   3432741 [0]
 2   3808497 [0]
 1   3809241 [15]
-- 2010-09-28 rep +260  = 13997
```

Once you start seeing things items in square brackets rather than round brackets (ie: `[x]` instead of `(y)`) like `[0]` it means you've reached your cap. In this case, all upvotes to my answers after reaching the cap give me 0 points, but the `[15]` denote I still earn reputation from accepted answers.

Knowing how the cap works, you can calculate how much rep you can still earn past 200 points. Count the # of accepts you have, multiply that by 15 and add to 200. For example:

```
 2   3591212 (10)
 3   XXXXXXX (-1)
 2   3856545 (10)
 1   3856545 (15)  << 1
 2   3856545 (10)
 2   3856683 (10)
 1   3856683 (15)  << 2
 2   3798442 (10)
 1   3798442 (15)  << 3
 2   3840707 (10)
-- 2010-10-04 rep +104  = 15109
```

With 3 accepted answers, I could get up to 245 points with 15 more upvotes (not counting accepts).

Bottom line is, you have a 200 reputation cap. Bounties and accepted answers are discarded from the cap calculations.

Answer (score 3):

The rep cap only applies to upvotes.  Accepted Answers and Bounties don't apply, despite adding 15 (for answers) or more to your reputation.