# Tell me when I reach the daily rep cap

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, top-bar

### This might look..

Like a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66837/youve-reached-your-daily-cap-icon) of an even older [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66837/youve-reached-your-daily-cap-icon) but the context is different here.

There was no **Reputation notifications** with the old design but now that the reputation notifications are implemented, it would be very nice to get my reputation feed to light up when I reach the daily cap. Instead of trying to figure out just if the 200 was reached by upvotes or accepted answers / bounties.

I know I could check in the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation but then I'd have to keep track  of the number of cap I had in the past and that's just not a viable solution.

Just make it light up as it does when you get a badge (maybe a different color would be nice too).

**It is not an important feature at all** but just another nice addition to the new top bar to make the users experience easier.

Comment: I get so few rep-caps this might not help me that much, but I still like it. Nice idea!

Comment: I nominate gold for the "different color".